# How to allow users to use custom domain name mapped to their user profile

Tags: ember.js, nginx, zend-framework2, web-hosting

I am building a network platform where the user profiles follow the URL format of website.com/username. However, I want to allow premium customers to be able to use custom domain names instead of website.com/username. So premium user should be able to use an external domain which gets mapped to the sub-domain.
I am using Zend Framework 2, EmberJS, and Amazon web services (Route 53) and Nginx.

Thanks so much in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own Route-Type for that. There's the [`RouteInterface`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/RouteInterface.php) for that. Actually you could always extend the Segment route for that, as basically you'll need a segment. The only difference being that your segment needs to match against the Database.

Alternatively, create a normal Segment route with the `:username` parameter and match that to a certain controller which then internally checks if the given username exists|isPremium and depending on the result, either forward to the userprofile or return to your home route.